# php: form doesn't evaluate correctly

Tags: php, forms, select

Newb here trying to make a simple temperature converter in which you enter the data and then select the filter to process the date through. I've never worked with a select before and haven't been able to figure out how to process the data to show only the value selected. Right now if you both ferinheight and celcius will print to the screen. I want to print only the value selected in the pull down/select.

```
<?php
    if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){//data is subnmitted, show it
        //$myTemp = (int)$_POST['myTemp'];// make it an int
        $myTemp = (float)$_POST['myTemp'];// float more forving

        $F = $myTemp  *  9/5 + 32;
        $C = $myTemp  *  9/5 - 32;

        if ($myFilter == 'f'){echo $F . "&ordm; ferinheight";}
        if ($myFilter == 'c'){echo $C . "&ordm; Celcius ";}

    }else{
?>
<form action="02temp.php" method="post">
    Enter Value to convert: <input type="text" name="myTemp" />
    <br />
    Select data filter:
    <select name="myFilter">
      <option value="f">F&ordm;</option>
      <option value="c">C&ordm;</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" /> <!--purposely blurred -->
</form>
<?php
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple mistakes:

1) You forgot to assign `$myFilter` a value.

```
 $myFilter = $_POST['myFilter']; // <-- You forgot this
```

2) But even if you did, you use the assignment operator (`=`) instead of the comparison operator (`==`) in your if statement making both of them true:

```
if ($myFilter = 'f'){echo $F . "&ordm; ferinheight";}
if ($myFilter = 'c'){echo $C . "&ordm; Celcius ";}
```

should be

```
if ($myFilter == 'f'){echo $F . "&ordm; ferinheight";}
if ($myFilter == 'c'){echo $C . "&ordm; Celcius ";}
```

Comment: About 1): I guess his code was supposed to run with REGISTER_GLOBALS turned on. Can't use that anymore though (security-wise).

Comment: Going to assume not since they assign `$myTemp`

Comment: Grrrr. I wonder if that changes their results. The code above should now be printing neither of them.

Comment: Right after I posted, i caught that i'd missed the assignment operator and retyped it.

Comment: I revised the if as follows which returns a white screen so i am not understanding something still I think: if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){//data is subnmitted, show it
   //$myTemp = (int)$_POST['myTemp'];// make it an int
   $myTemp = (float)$_POST['myTemp'];// float more forving

   $myFilter = $_POST['myFilter '];
   $F = $myTemp  *  9/5 + 32;
   $C = $myTemp  *  9/5 - 32;

   if ($myFilter == 'f'){echo $F . "&ordm; ferinheight";}
   if ($myFilter == 'c'){echo $C . "&ordm; Celcius ";}

Comment: I found the error (and edited John's answer). Reload the answer. There was a space in `['myFilter ']` which should have read as `['myFilter']` @Chezshire it worked for me. You won't get a blank screen now.

Comment: Cool - it works. I removed the space as you said, and i also moved '$myFilter = $_POST['myFilter'];' to come right before the two it's. I wanted to do this originally as bool (setting the select to true or false) but i wasn't able to form my question in a way that google returned any results i could understand.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Muchos gracias!

Comment: Prego amico mio @JohnConde